# Singleton OnPropertyChanged Not Firing

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, uwp

I have a class called DataModel where I am storing an `ObservableCollection` of projects. I was using a static `ObservableCollection`, but since I want to bind to it, and OnPropertyChanged doesn't seem to work correctly for static properties, I created it as a singleton:

```
public sealed class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private static readonly DataModel instance = new DataModel();
    private DataModel() { }

    public static DataModel Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    #region Projects
    private ObservableCollection<Project> projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>();
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects
    {
        get
        {
            return projects;
        }
        set
        {
            if (projects == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            projects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
        }
    }
    #endregion Projects

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Then when I click a button,

```
Project newProject = new Project() { Title = "Test" };
DataModel.Instance.Projects.Add(newProject);
```

From what I could come up with from various sources, this ought to work correctly. However, the `OnPropertyChanged` event is never called. If I do

```
DataModel.Instance.Projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>();
```

it is called. But adding a Project to the collection won't call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnPropertyChanged` is only automatically fired when that property is reassigned. That is why reassigning your entire collection causes it to be fired. Modifying the collection fires the collection's own `CollectionChanged` event instead, since you're not actually changing the `Projects` reference, just mutating the same collection it's referring to.

If your collection is bound to a control's `ItemsSource` property correctly, e.g.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"/>
```

where the data context is your `DataModel` instance, you should not need to do anything beyond adding the new item.

If you need to do something when the collection is changed, subscribe to its `CollectionChanged` event instead:

```
private DataModel()
{
    Projects.CollectionChanged += Projects_CollectionChanged;
}

private void Projects_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        // An item was added...
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha! I was looking in the entirely wrong place. I went and forgot to set the DataContext. \*facepalm\*. Just assumed it was something with the DataModel, since this is the first time I'm doing it like this-- therefore it won't work for the first 10 hours. However, your answer confirmed that it was indeed correct, so accepting.

Comment: @Shawn: Good thing I made sure to account for that then :)

Answer (score 0):

I expect it NOT to work. Because you are adding item to Observation collection in which case there is no reason setter would be called and thus *OnPropertyChanged*. That's why it works when you initialize *DataModel.Instance.Projects* from calling code. You could call property changed explicitly as below:

```
Project newProject = new Project() { Title = "Test" };
DataModel.Instance.Projects.Add(newProject);
DataModel.Instance.OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
```

Disclaimer: Although this is possible, you really need not do this. That is why they have provided us with *ObservableCollection*. Any item/s added or removed to/from such collection are automatically notified to the View. If this was not true, why would anybody use *ObservableCollection* instead of simple *List* for data bindings.